# Matching two very similar images

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, opencv

I have two images for the same object from the almost same perspective (no more than 1-2 degrees or 1-2 mm is acceptable).
I want to change the perspective of one of them to match exactly the other so I can make subtraction between them successfully to get a complete black result if there is no change of the content of the object.
many thanks

Comment: the difference between those two images described as "almost same perspective" seems a little inadequate for a quantitative answer if that is what you are looking for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all these answers fail to provide a descent methodology.

You should consider "the closeness" of the images as the availability of the initial pose and cast this as a registration problem. The solution can typically be obtained through a least-squares adjustment, i.e., by minimizing the distances of the model points (from first image) to their corresponding image points. In case of a perspective distortion, you could optimize the 9 parameters of the homography matrix. Methods like [Lukas Kanade](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24677-lucas-kanade-affine-template-tracking), [ESM](http://far.in.tum.de/pub/benhimane2004iros1/benhimane2004iros1.pdf) or [hyperplane tracking](http://campar.in.tum.de/twiki/pub/Chair/TeachingWs09MATDCV/Juries-Hyperplane.pdf) are some ways to do that. In essence, the procedure is similar to [ICP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_closest_point), where an iterative procedure is applied.

[Here](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~cmei/articles/single_view_track_ITRO.pdf) is one work, extending ESM and comparing a few methods. If your camera is calibrated, you could benefit from some [alternative methods](http://handheldar.icg.tugraz.at/download/Pi11-ISMAR.pdf).

Note that, to begin with, one could always resort to a simple approach, where you try different combinations of rigid motion $[-2,2]$ degrees for rotation and $[-5,5]$ pixels for translation. Then transform your template with all possible poses (in this case ~$40-50$). Then interpolate the sum of squared differences or normalized cross correlation scores in the pose space (6DOF freedom or 9DOF homography) to get a subpixel accurate refinement. This should give you a rough yet a better alignment. Keep in mind that you could also use this scheme iteratively.

If you have absolutely no clue on how to do any of these, check out [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25435/Image-Alignment-Algorithms-Part-II).

Comment: That is exactly the answer that I have implemented recently. I used KLT then RANSAC for the homography plus gamma correction which solves all the problem.  Many thanks @Tbirdal

Answer (score 0):

What @creator means that it is not possible. You have two images say matrix A and B. You want to calculate say C=B-A so that A-B+C=0. If you do not have a model to go from A to C how can you find C? In other words you need B to get A-B if you do not know or do not have model to go from A to B, you cannot.

Comment: Thanks , but is not possible to find similar feature then try to build that missing model?

Comment: No. We need a model otherwise not possible as no information is available. I would say model is the required information.